# Spring-using library defined beans conflict with application

Tags: java, spring, autowired, spring-bean

I have several spring-boot web applications and a single integration library used by all the web applications. The integration library makes use of Spring for DI and defines several of its own `@Bean`s with explicit names assigned, notably an `ObjectMapper` used for doing its own deserialization from API calls.

Here is the `ObjectMapper` bean definition in the integration library (in a `@Configuration` class):

```
@Bean(name = "Blah.APIObjectMapper")
public ObjectMapper blahAPIObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
        .configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false)
        .setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);

    return mapper;
}
```

Elsewhere in the library, this `ObjectMapper` is `@Autowired` up with a specific `@Qualifier`, like so:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("Blah.APIObjectMapper")
private ObjectMapper blahAPIObjectMapper;
```

---

The problem occurs in the web applications. This custom `ObjectMapper` bean defined in the integration library conflicts with the default-configured `ObjectMapper` bean which I have no control over.

The error is:

**org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException**: Error creating bean with name 'mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]: : No qualifying bean of type [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: Blah.APIObjectMapper,_halObjectMapper; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: **No qualifying bean of type [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: Blah.APIObjectMapper,_halObjectMapper**

---

**Q:** How do I prevent the library's `Blah.APIObjectMapper` from conflicting with the spring-boot default `ObjectMapper` apparently named `_halObjectMapper`?

I am not using any XML configuration for Spring. Everything is annotation-based.

Answer (score 0):

_halObjectMapper looks like the name of the bean created by spring-hateoas via @EnableHypermediaSupport.

Spring boot accepts the bean with name objectMapper if multiple beans of type ObjectMapper exist. You can therefore get round the problem by creating a 3rd object mapper bean with the name objectMapper and could even use one of the existing ObjectMapper beans.

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper(ObjectMapper _halObjectMapper) {
   return _halObjectMapper;
}
```

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for. I'd like to avoid introducing any hacks like this into the web applications. Ideally the integration library should be able to hold its own against whatever web applications I integrate it with a minimum of fuss.

Comment: You should take a look at http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper

Answer (score 0):

You can define your ObjectMapper bean as the primary provider. This is an example.

```
@Primary
@Bean(name = "Blah.APIObjectMapper")
public ObjectMapper blahAPIObjectMapper() {
```

The issue and solution were discussed at [this thread](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5984).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it exchanging library of Hateoas:

**Before:**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**After:**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
</dependency>
```